# How can I pass the method from ac Activity to OnClickListener

Tags: android

Hello I have 2 classes for a Memory Game:
One is the NV1 who have the method, for exampe:

```
 public class Nv1 extends Activity{

protected int cardsUp;

protected int currentIndex = -1;

protected int lastIndex = -1;

protected int cardEquals = 0;

protected int lifes = 3;
protected TextView lifes_txt;

protected Handler handler;

protected int [] imgIds = {
        R.id.img_1,
        R.id.img_2,
        R.id.img_3,
        R.id.img_4,
};
```

An another class NVListener that implements OnClickListener.

```
   public class CardsListener implements OnClickListener{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
```

### ------------

**I need to call the method from my Activity to CardsListener. How could I do that?**

Comment: "Is this OK"? Why not just test and see if the code compiles, and does what you need it to do?

Comment: Because I already did it

Comment: So, what went wrong? What happened that shouldn't have, or what didn't happen that should have? Being specific will get you the most help.

Comment: I need to call the method from my Activity to the class CardListener implements OnClickListener

Comment: You said you created an interface but I cannot see it in your code.

Comment: Not quite sure what "call the method from my Activity to CardsListener" means, if you mean calling method from Activity IN the listener, just make the listener a inner class of the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Method A : Make the listener abstract, implement the abstract method onClick in the Activity
(recommended, listener can be reused easily, easier to debug)

Example:

In SampleActivity.java

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Your code here.....
        // findViewById()..... etc.

        b.setOnClickListener(new SomeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                someMethod();   
            }
        });

    }

     public void someMethod(){
        Log.d("Log Tag","Some Message");
     }


}
```

In SomeListener.Java

```
//make it abstract
public abstract class SomeListener implements OnClickListener{
//put your own method,variables inside
//do not override onClick()

}
```

Method B : Create a constructor with the Activity as a input parameter. Save the activity instance and call its method freely (less recommended : not flexible, and not logical IMO)

In SomeListener.Java

```
public class SomeListener implements OnClickListener {
    private SampleActivity mAct;

    public SomeListener(SampleActivity act){
        mAct = act;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         mAct.someMethod();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I know but i can't do with that form. I need to use 2 classes

Comment: @Azreal94  This solution uses 2 classes. Do you mean 2 .java file? If it is homework requirement can you post that also?

Comment: Actually if the listener is something as easy as calling a method in the activity you don't even need to create a listener class, an anonymous listener can do the job.

Comment: @Azreal94 forgot to tag you in previous comment.

Comment: The problem is that I'm creating a Memory Game and I have to explain. So I cannot explain something that is to large. That's why I want to have a class who implements onclicklistener and pass the method from the activity

Comment: I think I will have todo do with the second form. In the "someMethod()" I create like a getMethod. But my problem is that like 2 method I need to create in that Listener and that is the problem :S

Comment: Not sure you want to hold on to an activity. that's a LOT of memory to hold on to. if anything, maybe you should have it the other way around. have the activity implement the listener